# Order 12 phrase for trust wallet

Tags: wallet, wallet-recovery, python, mnemonic-seed, trust-wallet

I have 12 phrases for trust wallet but he is not arranged in the right way.
What is the solution? Code python with bip39!! How !?

Answer (score 4):

12 words have only  12! = 479'001'600 possible orders.

Create a script that

- iterates through all possible orders
- test whether the 12 words have a valid checksum
- if so, generate the relevant output scripts and check whether they have received coins in the past

Preferably iterate the combinations in a way that it will test the ones you consider more likely earlier.